# Perl: How to replace a string in file with a paragraph

Tags: perl, sed

I need to replace a token in a file with a multi-line paragrah, which has several line breakers inside it if the paragraph is represented as a string.

If I use sed the usually for a string to string replacement, the line breakers inside the new string would complain.

So now I want to open the file and seek to that token location, then write the new content into the file from there, but not sure how to achieve that. Can anybody help?

EDIT:

Looks like I probably can put both the file and the content to be inserted as arrays then use splice in perl. Might not be the easiest way though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
perl -i -pe's/token/foo\nbar\nbaz\n/g' file
```

You can't really insert into a file. Just like inserting into a string, you must first move the remainder of the string out of the way. With files, it's easier just to copy the entire file.

The provided code opens `file`, deletes `file`, creates `file`, then copies (with substitutions) from the open handle to the new handle.

It's my understanding that `sed` can do this too. It's my understanding that `sed` also uses `-i` to enable this feature.

Comment: This is great, but how can I run it inside a script? Do I have to use $^I?

Comment: The same way you were planning on using `sed`. You could also use `$^I`, Or you could follow the step-by-step instructions I gave you!

Comment: Thanks a lot. I found a way using $^I and it worked.

Answer (score 1):

Check out: [`How do I change, delete, or insert a line in a file, or append to the beginning of a file?`](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlfaq5.html#How-do-I-change%2c-delete%2c-or-insert-a-line-in-a-file%2c-or-append-to-the-beginning-of-a-file%3f)

The easiest solutions will be to either use perl's [`$INPLACE_EDIT`](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlvar.html), optionally done as a one liner like demonstrated by ikegami, or perhaps to use [`Tie::File`](http://perldoc.perl.org/Tie/File.html).